# Bending the Android platform rules for parental app to a max

Tags: android

because my questions might sound a bit suspicious, first some background: I'm writing an parental screen time control app. I am a seasoned java programmer with some Windows Phone background just learning the Android platform.

The app would run at startup (I understand that services can listen for a boot event and run) and when a violation of screen time is detected it would nuke all user processes that weren't around when the service started. Or lock the screen or some other annoyance every minute. No problems, right?

The kid will the try to terminate the process. I understand that this cannot be prevented on an unrooted device but a pair of processed could be used to bootstrap each other when the sibling dies?

Then the kid will try to uninstall the application, something that is also not possible on unrooted devices. I can listen to the uninstall event but by then the app is gone. Here is the tricky part, can I somehow reinstall automatically here? The application can ask any permission it wants on first install if it can help with the background reinstall

I understand that many of the features required here are nontrivial because that could be used for making, well, PITA apps. But I'm just trying to redistribute the misery my kids are giving me with screen control ;-)

Thankful for pointers,
  A sadistic parent

Comment: change the title. here comes the hordes of downvotes ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer. I'm new here so I didn't know the local diva-rules ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for an [Admin app](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

this will allow you to put some restriction. and you can listen for event for deactivation where intern you can reset the device if necessary.